# Nature of metric spaces

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $X$ be a metric space, and $Y$ be a closed subset of $X$ such that the distance between any two points in $Y$ is at most $1$:

- is $Y$ compact ?
- is any continuous function $Y\to \mathbb{R}$ bounded?
- can $Y$ be non open in $X$?

I have recently started to learn topology. So thinking of the notion of a space with different metric spaces is new to me.

Here when i try to think of this problem, initially I take some example space with a usual metric and then check if the above conditions satisfy all the time, then I wonder if the space can have another metric where the conditions are not satisfied.
When I take a bounded interval on $\mathbb{R}$ all the above are satisfied but I need some hints / suggestions to check for other spaces and how to account for all of them?

Comment: Infinite sets with discrete metric?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 
If I take the discrete metric space and look at its points, under this metric it looks as if all the points in interval or any subset of $R$ are isolated. Now Y need not be compact because $X-Y$ may not be open and countinuous function not bounded as it is mapped on isolated points, Y can be an open subset. 
Is this reasoning correct?

Comment: No:  all subsets are open.  But only finite subsets are compact.

Comment: For the first question just take the ball of radius 1/2 in an infinite dimensional vector space. Riesz's theorem gives you the rest

Answer (score 3):

Let $d$ be any metric. Then $d'(x,y)=\min\{d(x,y),1\}$ defines a bounded metric inducing the same topology. So a boundedness assumption on your set isn't going to guarantee any topological properties.

Comment: Thanks, I am starting to see what are topological properties and what are not.